# How to convert datetime string with timezone to local datetime

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, php-carbon

I have a string in this form: `2023-08-25T11:52:00+01:30`
How can I make local PHP datetime object with proper timezone set? I am using Carbon, but it does not recognize timezone at the end and simply removes it.

```
Carbon::create('2023-08-25T11:52:00+01:30');
```

I also try to use createFromFormat()

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', '2023-08-25T11:52:00+01:30');
```

but it also does not work.

Comment: Carbon::createFromFormat(**$format**, $date);

Comment: You are right but it also does not work.

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem description